# Why is my bankMoney value becoming NaN instead of the number

Tags: javascript, function, variables, var

The title explains it all. When I run the code, on line 139 the bankMoney value becoms NaN instead of a number. I'm pretty sure the problem is in a function where I define a value that changes the value. These would be `payDay`, `intrest`, or `propertyIncome`.

If anyone could help me, I would be overly greatful, as I have been working all day on this code, and this one bug is preventing me from coding forward.

I understand I have alot of variables defined in random spots, if anyone decides to fix this with a machine, or manually, I would love if I could have the edited code, but this is not needed as it isn't a problem for me.

The code is :

```
var intrest = function(intrest) {
    if(bankMoney > 0) {
        positiveIncome(0)
    }
    if(bankMoney < 0) {
        negativeIncome(0)
    }
}
var age = prompt("How old do you want your character to be? (Will be randomized if not between 20 and 100.)")
if(age > 100) {
    age = Math.floor((Math.random()*81) +20)
}
else if(age < 20) {
    age = Math.floor((Math.random()*81) +20)
}
var randomVariable1 = " Years old"
var randomVariable2 = " Press 'OK' if you like this age, or 'Cancel' to have it randomized."
var ageConfirm = confirm("Your character is now " +age +randomVariable1 +randomVariable2)
if(ageConfirm === true) {}
else {
    age = Math.floor((Math.random()*81) +20)
}
confirm("Your character is now " +age +randomVariable1)
var salary = 10000
var bankMoney = 120000
var bank = prompt("choice a bank. (Put in the number, not the name.) (You only get to do this once, so choose carefully.     1. A&A Positive income: 10% Negative income: 25%     2. B&C Positice income: 5% Negative income: 7%     3. Limburgdi International Positive income: 12.5% negative income: 30%     4.S&N Positive uncome: 2.5% Negative income: 5%")
if(bank < 1) {
    Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1)
}
if(bank > 4) {
    Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1)
}
if(bank === 1) {
    function positiveIncome(positiveincome) {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.1)
    }
    function negativeIncome(negativeincome) {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.25)
    }
}
if(bank === 2) {
    function positiveIncome(positiveincome) {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.05)
    }
    function negativeIncome(negativeincome) {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.07)
    }
}
if(bank === 3) {
    function positiveIncome(positiveincome) {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.125)
    }
    function negativeIncome (negativeincome) {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.3)
    }
}
if(bank === 4) {
     function positiveIncome(positiveincome) {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.025)
    }
    function negativeIncome(negativeincome) {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.05)
    }
}
var withdrawl1 = prompt("How much would you like to withdrawl? MUST Be GREATER THAN 1 if not greater than one, it will randomize, and you may not like the outcome.")
if(withdrawl1 < 1) {
    withdrawl1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*bankMoney - 1) +1)
}
var pocketMoney = withdrawl1 - withdrawl1 * 0.09
bankMoney = bankMoney - withdrawl1
var randomVariable3 = " Your pocket money is $"
confirm("Your new bank balance is $" +bankMoney +randomVariable3 +pocketMoney)
var jumped = Math.floor(Math.random()*75000)
if(jumped > 50000) {
    confirm("You escaped being jumped by four guys. A bounty hunter gave you $250 for leading the criminals to him.")
    pocketMoney = pocketMoney + 250
}
else {
     var jumpedChoice = confirm("You were jumped by four guys, they took half of your pocketmoney! Press okay to continue about your day, or cancel to chace them down.")
     if(jumpedChoice === true) {
        pocketMoney = pocketMoney - pocketMoney * 0.5
    }
    else {
        var trip = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000)
        if(trip < 75000) {
            confirm("You tripped and fell, and they came back and took the rest of your money.")
            pocketMoney = 0
        }
        else {
        confirm("You found them, and they were cornered between you and the police. They were forced to give you your money back.")
        }
    }
}
var fired = Math.floor(Math.random()*75000)
if(fired > 70000) {
    var newJob = prompt("You lost your job. Choose a new job. Put in the number, not the job title. 1)Cashier  2)HairStylist  3)Driver  4)Janitor  5)Landscaper")
    if(newJob === 1) {
        salary = 500
    }
    if(newJob === 2) {
        salary === 250
    }
    if(newJob === 3) {
        salary = 750
    }
    if(newJob === 4) {
        salary = 200
    }
    if(newJob === 5) {
        salary = 1000
    }
}
function payDay(payDay) {
    bankMoney = bankMoney + (salary - (salary * 0.05))
    intrest(0)
    propertyIncome(0)
    confirm("You have been paid,and your bank account has been given intrest. your new bank balance is: $" +bankMoney)
}
var house = prompt("Pick a house. Put in the number, not the name. (property income is 10% with $0 tax.  1)Mansion:$800,000  2)RanchSyle:$250,000  3)TwoStory:$300,000  4)House:$50,000")
if(house === 1) {
    var houseIncome = 80000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 800000
}
if(house === 2) {
   var houseIncome = 25000
   bankMoney = bankMoney - 250000
}
if(house === 3) {
    var houseIncome = 30000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 300000
}
if(house === 4) {
    var houseIncome = 5000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 5000
}
function propertyIncome(propertyIncome) {
    bankMoney = bankMoney + houseIncome
}
payDay(0)
var transactionSubVar = 0
function transaction(transaction) {
    transactionSubVar = prompt("Here's a bank transaction. Put in a positive number to deposit, or a negative to withdrawl. if your deposit will give you a negative pocketMoney, the bank won't allow it.")
    if((transactionSubVar - pocketMoney) < 0) {
        confirm("The bank won't allow this transaction, sorry.")
    }
    if((transactionSubVar - pocketMoney) > 0) {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + transactionSubVar
        pocketMoney = pocketMoney - transactionSubVar
    }
}
transaction(0)
confirm("Your bank Money is now $" +bankMoney +randomVariable3 +pocketMoney)
```

Comment: a demo always helps. could you do a fiddle?

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) lets you do a mockup of your code so that you can replicate your problem for users on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When evaluating the user's house choice, you're comparing their input with various values using [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_when_to_use_them) (`===`):

```
if(house === 1) {
    var houseIncome = 80000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 800000
}
if(house === 2) {
   var houseIncome = 25000
   bankMoney = bankMoney - 250000
}
if(house === 3) {
    var houseIncome = 30000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 300000
}
if(house === 4) {
    var houseIncome = 5000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 5000
}
```

Since [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) returns a string, all of these comparisons return `false` and `houseIncome` remains `undefined`. Adding `undefined` to `bankMoney` ultimately yields `NaN`.

You can use `==` instead of `===`:

```
if(house == 1) {
    var houseIncome = 80000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 800000
}
if(house == 2) {
   var houseIncome = 25000
   bankMoney = bankMoney - 250000
}
if(house == 3) {
    var houseIncome = 30000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 300000
}
if(house == 4) {
    var houseIncome = 5000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 5000
}
```

Or use `parseInt` before using strict equality:

```
house = parseInt(house, 10);

if(house === 1) {
    var houseIncome = 80000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 800000
}
if(house === 2) {
   var houseIncome = 25000
   bankMoney = bankMoney - 250000
}
if(house === 3) {
    var houseIncome = 30000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 300000
}
if(house === 4) {
    var houseIncome = 5000
    bankMoney = bankMoney - 5000
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9tfgcr5p/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the parseFloat() function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp?

Also, I notice you are passing a lot of variables to your functions that aren't used.  For instance

```
function propertyIncome(propertyIncome) {
    bankMoney = bankMoney + houseIncome
}
```

does not use the (propertyIncome) that gets passed to it.